# Show that $ \sup\{L(f,P)+L(g,Q):P, Q \text { are partitions of } [a,b]\}$ equals $\sup\{L(f,P)+L(g,P):P\text { are partitions of } [a,b]\}$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

I will be using terminology and notation from Spivak's *Calculus*. Please let me know if clarification is needed (as I am unsure if there are different conventions used outside of this book). $L(f,P)$ stands for "The lower sum of the function $f$ on the finite partition $P$ of some interval $[a,b]$."

I'd like to know if this is an adequate argument.

---

Consider the following sets, where $f$ and $g$ are both bounded over $[a.b]$:

$\mathcal L_1=\{L(f,P)+L(g,Q):P, Q \text { are partitions of } [a,b]\}$

$\mathcal L_2=\{L(f,P)+L(g,P):P\text { are partitions of } [a,b]\}$

Because $f$ and $g$ are both bounded on $[a,b]$, it is clear that $\{L(f,P) : P \text { is a partition of } [a,b]\}$  and $\{L(g,P) : P \text { is a partition of } [a,b]\}$ are both bounded sets.  Therefore, $\mathcal L_1$ and $\mathcal L_2$ both have upper bounds. As such, they must both have least upper bounds (*LUB*s). Let $\sup\mathcal L_1=\alpha_1$ and $\sup\mathcal L_2=\alpha_2$. **Show that $\alpha_1=\alpha_2$.**

---

To prove this we will make use of a lemma which states:

> For partitions $P$, $Q$ of $[a,b]$, if $P \subseteq Q$ then $L(f,P) \leq L(f,Q)$

Note $\mathcal L_2 \subseteq \mathcal L_1$. Therefore, $\alpha_2 \not \gt \alpha_1$. Next, suppose $\alpha_2 \lt \alpha_1$.

Because $\alpha_1$ is the *LUB* of $\mathcal L_1$, we know that for any $\varepsilon \gt 0$, there exists partitions $P'$ and $Q'$ of $[a,b]$ such that $\alpha_1-\varepsilon \lt L(f,P')+L(g,Q')$.

Let $\displaystyle\varepsilon=\frac{\alpha_1-\alpha_2}{2}$. Note that $\alpha_1-\varepsilon \gt \alpha_2$. Then we have that there are partitions $P', Q'$ such that $\alpha_2 \lt L(f,P')+L(g,Q')$.

Now consider the partition $S=P' \cup Q'$, which is, itself, a partition of $[a,b]$. Clearly, $P' \subseteq S$ and $Q' \subseteq S$. Then, by our lemma, we know that $L(f,S)+L(g,S) \geq L(f,P')+L(g,Q')$. Therefore, $L(f,S)+L(g,S) \gt \alpha_2$. But this contradicts the claim that $\alpha_2$ is the *LUB* of $\mathcal L_2$.

So we must have $\alpha_1=\alpha_2$.

---

**Edit**

Note that a similar proof can be used to show that if:

$\mathcal L_1=\{U(f,P)+U(g,Q):P, Q \text { are partitions of } [a,b]\}$

$\mathcal L_2=\{U(f,P)+U(g,P):P\text { are partitions of } [a,b]\}$

then the $\inf{\mathcal L_1}=\inf{\mathcal L_2}$

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is correct, but I would have argued in a shorter way, applying similar arguments.

Only one inequality requires a proof. For two partitions $P$ and $Q$ there holds $$L(f,P)+L(g,Q)\le L(f,P\cup Q)+L(g,P\cup Q)\le a_2$$
Now we consider the left hand side and take $\sup$ with respect to $P$ and then with respect to $Q$ to obtain
$$\sup_PL(f,P)+\sup_QL(g,Q)\le a_2$$ Hence $a_1\le a_2.$

Comment: I'm having a little difficulty seeing the connection between your proof and my post. Could you clarify? Also, I believe $L(P \cup Q,f)+L(P \cup Q,g)=L(P\cup Q, f+g)$ is incorrect. I think it needs to be $\leq$.

Comment: I feel like you are treating my $\mathcal L_2$ set as being equivalent to the set of all $L(f+g, P)$. But I do not think that this is true.

Comment: @S.Cramer Sorry, I was not careful enough reading your claim. But now it is even shorter, and hopefully correct.

Comment: My proof results in a different claim - yet you say my reasoning is correct. I have that $\alpha_1 \lt \alpha_2$ is a contradiction.

Comment: @S.Cramer In your proof you write "Next, suppose α2<α1."

Comment: Yes...and it results in a contradiction. And $a_2 \gt a_1$ can immediately be ruled out...meaning that all that remains is for $a_1=a_2$

Comment: @S.Cramer In my answer I have shown $a_1\le a_2,$ the essential inequality, as $a_2\le a_1$ we get for free.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I am a little confused. If we can explicitly show that $\alpha_1=\alpha_2$, why stop the proof at $\alpha_1 \leq \alpha_2$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136084/discussion-between-ryszard-szwarc-and-s-cramer).